# Check if a file is going to be uploaded? CodeIgniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload

I have a form with few inputs and a file input. 
I want to check whethere the file input is empty or not.
If it is empty do not try to upload, if it is not then try to upload it.

I tried something like this:

```
$upld_file = $this->upload->data();
    if(!empty($upld_file)) 
    {
    //Upload file
    }
```

Comment: You need to tell us what is actually going wrong/not working.

Comment: Actually when I was doing this form it seemed to work. This form is for changing user's profile information.
I want when the user do not select any file to execute the code for uploading the file.

Basically to chek if the file input is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you use codeigniter's file uploader class... and call `$this->upload->do_upload();` in a conditional statement ahd check if its true.

```
<?php 
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
```

**The user_guide explains this in detail:** http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

However,
if you are dead set on checking whether a file has been "uploaded" aka.. submitted BEFORE you call this class (not sure why you would). You can access PHPs `$_FILES` super global.. and use a conditional to check if size is > 0.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

**Update 2:** This is actual working code, i use it on an avatar uploader myself using CI 2.1

```
<?php
//Just in case you decide to use multiple file uploads for some reason.. 
//if not, take the code within the foreach statement

foreach($_FILES as $files => $filesValue){
    if (!empty($filesValue['name'])){
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }else{
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }//nothing chosen, dont run.
}//end foreach
```

Comment: Okay, but what if the field is left empty? Errors would appear, but I want to do_upload() only if the field is not empty (that means the user tries to upload an avatar for their profile?

Comment: see my edited answer. Use a conditional $_FILES if/else statement.

Comment: Thanks. I did this:
`$avatar = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
if(!empty($avatar)) 
{ //upload file
}`

Comment: I wish there were a better way to do this without using the `$_FILES` special, but so be it...  Room for improvement on the CI library!

Answer (score 0):

Probably do need more info.  But basically, using the codeigniter upload class do something like this:

```
$result = $this->upload->do_upload();

if($result === FALSE)
{

    // handle error
    $message = $this->upload->display_errors();
}
else
{
    // continue
}
```

There is a lot of functionality in codeigniter, probably don't need to re-invent the wheel here.